# how to get the content in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm a beginner in learning objective c.
I want to make my iphone app do this thing:

- if touch A area, do XXXXX
- if touch B area, do YYYYY
- if touch A&B areas at same time, do ZZZZZZ

I think the first thing I need to do is to save the Coordinate of every touch,
and then to check all the coordinates in the right area or not.

I Use NSMutableArray to save the Coordinate, but I don't know how to get the content in the array.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    NSMutableArray *Xarray;
    NSMutableArray *Yarray;

    Xarray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[touches count]];
    Yarray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[touches count]];


    for(UITouch *touch in touches)
    {   
        CGPoint pstart=[touch locationInView:self.view];
        [Xarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:pstart.x]];
        [Yarray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:pstart.y]];
    }    
}
```

thanks very much!

Comment: Why do you need to *store* the touches at all; why not fire your XXXXX, YYYYY, ZZZZZ from within the `touchesBegin` method?  I think your solution will be expensive anyway, creating and populating an object each time the screen is touched (not to mention what looks like a memory leak using `arrayWithCapacity` rather than `initWithCapacity`).

Comment: I got the sense! thanks you all very well!

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, whose documentation is at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray where you'll find, e.g., that the method for accessing an element in an array is called `objectAtIndex:`. So, e.g., `Xarray objectAtIndex:0` gets the first element in the array. There are also methods for extracting multiple elements at once, iterating over all the objects in the array, etc.

For your application you might actually want `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` (the test would be looking for positions within a given area).

Comment: NSLog(@"x:%d,y:%d",[Xarray objectAtIndex:i],[Yarray objectAtIndex:i]);
I have tried this code to check my coordinate is correct or not.But the result is not my thought. The outputs always like this"x:225058736,y:225058752" I don't know why.. very thanks!

Comment: The things returned by `objectAtIndex:` are objects, not primitive types. In this case they're `NSNumber`s. (An `NSArray` can only hold objects, not `int`s or `float`s or whatever.) If you want to format them with `%d` then you need to extract an `int` value with `intValue`, though I notice that the numbers you're actually putting in there are floating-point.